# how to get number of sub files in PHP?

Tags: php, file

```
[root@file nutch-0.9]# ls resume/
crawldb  index  indexes  linkdb  segments
```

like the above example,

how to get number of sub files(can be file or directory) in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

use the PHP function readdir or scandir in PHP, get the file list as an array and get a count on the array.  you may have to do some tweaking to avoid the current and parent directory ( . and .. )

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 1):

```
function count_files($path) {
    return count(array_diff(scandir($path), array(".", "..")));
}
```

Comment: that will include . and ..   and why do you return 1 if it's not a directory?

Comment: as well as any hidden files, which ls doesn't show by default

Comment: @SilentGhost Fixed. And I thought (can be file or directory) referred to the argument. Obviously, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The examples for [readdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) are most probably what you are looking for.